# How to fix length of characters in DataGrid cells

Tags: .net, winforms, c#-4.0, datagrid

I have a datagrid with a column, ID with values like 1,2,3,4,5....10,11,12,13...
I want all the values should be of length two, means i want the values as 01,02,03....10,11,12...
How to do it?

**EDIT**
I am using Winforms.

**EDIT**

```
    if (dg.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Id")
    {
        try
        {
            //e.Value = String.Format("{0:00.0}", e.Value);

            DataGridViewCellStyle ca = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
            ca.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            ca.Format = "d2";

            dg.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].DefaultCellStyle = ca;
            e.FormattingApplied = true;
        }
        catch (FormatException)
        {
            e.FormattingApplied = false;
        }
    }
```

Here iam able to change backcolor and forecolor but the text format remains the same, no matter what i do. I even tried using String.Format (commented line) but its not working either.
I tried your code also, its not working. don't know whats wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Formatting the string with ToString("00") worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

(DataGridView)

For a DataGridView, try setting the `Format` property of the `DefaultCellStyle` like [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f9x2790s%28v=VS.90%29.aspx):

```
this.dataGridView1.Columns["COLUMN_NAME"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "d2";
```

---

(WinForms DataGrid answer)

In WinForms, MSDN says there's a [Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridtextboxcolumn.format.aspx) property on the DataGridTextBoxColumn; I don't use WinForms often enough to verify that that's the correct type of column.

---

(Web Forms answer)

You can use the [DataFormatString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.dataformatstring.aspx) property on the column:

```
DataFormatString="{0:D2}"
```

Comment: Added WinForms (potential) answer

Comment: in msdn, they have given the explanation with Datagrid which is not available in Visual Studio 2010 (replaced by DatagridView). as i am very new to .net, finding it tough to crack the solution. still thanks

Comment: Added a potential DataGridView answer